# ASP.NET VB Set Datalist to edit mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

i have a `button` which is on top of a `Datalist`. Each time users do a search, the records returned will be bind to the `Datalist`.

Code for the button:
`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="edit"/>`

Code for the Datalist:

```
<asp:DataList ID="UserMatrixDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" CellSpacing="6" RepeatLayout="Table" BorderWidth="5">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="table">
            <col width="130">
            <col width="800">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Level</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLevel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Level")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <table class="table">
            col width="130">
                <col width="800">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Level</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLevel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Level")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

At the .vb file, i have:

```
Protected Sub UserMatrixDataList_EditCommand(source As Object, e As DataListCommandEventArgs)

    For i = 0 To UserMatrixDataList.Items.Count

        UserMatrixDataList.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex
        UserMatrixDataList.DataBind()

    Next
End Sub
```

However, nothing happens after clicking on the `button`. Any idea where am I doing it wrong? Or is it even possible to implement such method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the button is outside the Datalist, it will not use the `EditCommand` method. But you can still set the EditIndex with that button.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'if you need this line depends on how and where you are binding the data to the datalist
    UserMatrixDataList.DataSource = source

    UserMatrixDataList.EditIndex = 6
    UserMatrixDataList.DataBind
End Sub
```

But you can only set one item to `edit` at a time.